# Function in javascript giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a dynamic list. This is my source

```
$('#friend_list').prepend('<div class="row friend margin-bottom"><div class="col-sm-2 text-primary"></div><div class="col-sm-3 text-primary">'+pending[index]['friendUname']+'</div><div class="col-sm-3 text-primary"></div><div class="col-sm-2 text-primary"></div><div class="col-sm-2 text-primary"><a onclick="accept_request('+pending[index]['friendUname']+','+getSession('uname')+')" href="#">ACCEPT</a></div></div>');
```

The result displayed in the html is

```
<div class="row friend margin-bottom">
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-primary"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-primary">alizia</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-primary"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-primary"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-primary">
            <a onclick="accept_request(alizia,saad)" href="#">ACCEPT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a function at the bottom of my page.

```
function accept_request(frienduname,uname){
    console.log(frienduname + '.....' + uname);
}
```

But when I click the button, it gives me the following error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: alizia is not defined(…) VM11593 friends.html:1

Comment: Well... where have you defined your `alizia` variable? And `saad` too for that matter.

Comment: It is inside the onclick="accept_request('+pending[index]['friendUname']+','+getSession('uname')+')"

Comment: No, that's the value you're providing. If you want to show that value directly you need to wrap it in quotes

Comment: If "alizia" and "saad" are just strings use this: `accept_request('alizia','saad')`

Comment: ...aaand this is again one of the reasons why you shouldn't have inline event handlers.

Comment: I got it. Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed the variables not the strings for `alizia` and `saad`. Rory McCrossan  pointed this out in his comment.

You should change your html to include strings in the javascript by adding single quotes around the variables you are passing to your function.

```
 <a onclick="accept_request('alizia','saad')" href="#">ACCEPT</a>
```